# React & Bootstrap: How to make input box in a PureComponent Card update other instances of itself?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a list of Cards. Each Card is set up as a PureComponent. Each Card has an input box with a boolean. I'd like to make the user choose up to 3 cards. Once that max is hit, the rest of the input boxes should become disabled. My code currently has a reducer with two actions: makeProductDisabled and makeProductEnabled. It's updating one item at a time to be disabled, but it needs to be changed so that the rest of the non-checked items are disabled.

Reducer:

```js
export const productListReducer = (state, action) => {
    let position;
    switch (action.type) {
        case "makeProductDisabled":
            position = state.productList.map((e) => e.id).indexOf(action.value.id);
            return { ...state, ...state.productList[position].isProductDisabled = true };
        case "makeProductEnabled":
            position = state.productList.map((e) => e.id).indexOf(action.value.id);
            return { ...state, ...state.productList[position].isProductDisabled = false };

        default:
            return state; 
    }
};

export default productListReducer;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Card as a PureComponent:

```js
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Card from '../ui/card';
import Row from '../ui/custom/row';
import Col from '../ui/custom/col';
import CardBody from '../ui/card-body';
import Input from '../ui/custom/input';
import Label from '../ui/custom/label';
import FormCheck from '../ui/form-check';

class MyCard extends PureComponent {

    onToggleProductToCompare = (event) => {
        this.setIsProductDisabled(event);
    };

    setIsProductDisabled = (event) => {
        if (this.props.productCompareList.length > 3) {
            // TODO: find any products, that are not checked, to be disabled
            this.props.dispatch({type: "makeProductDisabled", value: this.props.product})
        } else {
            this.props.dispatch({ type: "makeProductEnabled", value: this.props.product})
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { product } = this.props;
        return (
            <Card>
                <CardBody>
                    <Row>
                        <Col md={5} lg={3}>
                            <FormCheck right>
                                <Label htmlFor={`compareProducts--${this.props.product.id}`} className='form-check-label'>Compare</Label>

                                <Input
                                    id={`compareProducts--${this.props.product.id}`}
                                    type="checkbox"
                                    
                                    // TODO: if length > 3, make the rest disabled.
                                    // else make all enabled
                                    disabled={this.props.product.isProductDisabled}
                                    checked={false}

                                    changed={this.onToggleProductToCompare}
                                />
                            </FormCheck>
                        </Col>
                        
                    </Row>
                </CardBody>
            </Card>
        )
    }
}

MyCard.propTypes = {
    product: PropTypes.object,
    dispatch: PropTypes.func
};

export default MyCard;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Could you include the code you have written so far in your question, and detail what is not working?

Comment: It seems like you should be using a regular component instead. The point of a PureComponent is to be a "dumb" component which has no sense of anything else. A PureComponent only accepts information and displays, it should have no control over another component. A good example of a PureComponent would be a page heading which displays something based on state.

Comment: @Tholle post now has my current code

Comment: @CWSites That would be my preference. But, I'm supposed to try to keep it as a PureComponent for now. I might just try to loop through the rest in setIsProductDisabled.

Comment: That would make more sense, use a different part of the code to determine if it should be enabled or not and the PureComponent will do whatever it is told.

Comment: It should be determined by the reducer (or the action if you use actions with side effects)

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where you would need to keep track of which cards are selected in the parent component of the cards and add an `isDisabled` prop to your Card component. When the max number is selected, you will set the `disabled` prop to true on the cards that are not selected.

```
const Parent = cards => {
    const [cardsSelected, setCardsSelected] = useState({});
    const hasMaxSelected = Object.keys(cardsSelected).length > 2;

    const toggleSelect = card => {
        if (cardsSelected[card.id]) {
            const newCards = { ...cardsSelected };
            delete newCards[card.id];
            setCardsSelected(newCards);
        } else {
            setCardsSelected({
                ...cardsSelected,
                [card.id]: true
            });
        }
    }

    return cards.map(card => {
        const isCardSelected = !!cardsSelected[card.id];
        return (
            <Child
                onSelect={() => toggleSelect(card)}
                isSelected={isCardSelected} 
                isDisabled={hasMaxSelected && !isCardSelected} 
            />;
        );
    });
}
```

This will re-render the array of cards every time one of the cards changes, which will pick up whether or not we're at the max number selected and which cards should be disabled when that happens.

Comment: The goal is to avoid a re-render of all the cards. I got it working by doing the logic in the PureComponent and using a reducer. This only causes one card to re-render, when necessary.

Comment: So your Child component will implement a shouldComponentUpdate method that will provide the logic to tell it not actually re-render itself (in most cases, with simple (non-nested object) props, a PureComponent would do this for you).